# Why opamp output doesn't match with the calculation?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

The actual current passing the load is 44mA, in below schematic the voltage across Rsense is 454mV and the opamp output is 4.52V. which is correct.

But when I replace the Rsense with a 0.1 ohm resistor the voltage across Rsense changes to 1.9mV and opamp output to 8.5mV!

Why current reading become way off when I change the resistor to a lower value? Is it because of the 5% resistors?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5Z06k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You might want to check your schematic.  I suspect your input resistors are going to the wrong sides of your sense resistor...this output will never leave 0.  Are you in fact running the op amp single ended?  I also think your current calculations are off by an order of magnitude, if the values here are right.

Comment: Is that really the op amp you are using?

Comment: @VoltageSpike yes it is a LM358N.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis Thanks, corrected the schematic.

Comment: Something is still wrong with your schematic...now you have no negative feedback.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Thanks, edited it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the input range of an LM358 goes all the way to the negative supply voltage (ground in this case), the output range does not. According to the TI datasheet, you are not guaranteed to get closer than 20mV to the negative supply rail.

Remember also that this amplifier has an input offset voltage of several millivolts.

Comment: Is CA3140 a good replacement for LM358N? for sensing current? if not can you please suggest a proper opamp for this purpose?

Comment: @newbie Have you tried the Google?  This isn't new ground, there are lots of examples.

Comment: Sorry, no, we don't recommend specific products here. Having said that, you should look for an op amp that has "rail-to-rail" inputs and outputs (RRIO) but check the datasheet to make sure they aren't exaggerating.

Comment: And an input offset voltage commensurate with the accuracy you want.

Answer (score 2):

> Elliot Alderson, gave the right practical answer. I got into it using the theoretical approach.

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSZGST.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using KCL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_{\text{R}_\text{L}}=\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_{\text{R}_\text{s}}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}=\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}=\text{I}_{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_{\text{R}_\text{s}}=\text{I}_{\text{R}_\text{L}}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Using KVL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_{\text{R}_\text{L}}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_\text{L}}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_\text{s}}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_\text{s}}=\frac{\text{V}_1-0}{\text{R}_\text{s}}=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_\text{s}}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_3-0}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_2-0}{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{op}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_\text{L}}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_\text{s}}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{op}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_\text{s}}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_\text{L}}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, when we have an ideal opamp we know that \$\text{V}_x:=\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_2=\text{V}_3\$. So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_\text{L}}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_\text{s}}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{op}-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_\text{s}}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_\text{L}}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Now, we can solve for the load current \$\text{I}_{\text{R}_\text{L}}\$ and assuming that \$\text{R}_1=\text{R}_2\$ and \$\text{R}_3=\text{R}_4\$, so we get:

$$\text{I}_{\text{R}_\text{L}}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}\left(\text{R}_\text{s}+\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)}{\text{R}_\text{L}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)+\text{R}_\text{s}\left(\text{R}_\text{L}+\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)}\tag5$$

Using your values we get:

$$\text{I}_{\text{R}_\text{L}}=\frac{11000+\text{R}_\text{s}}{220000+2220\text{R}_\text{s}}\tag6$$

So:

1. \$\text{R}_\text{L}=10\$:
   $$\text{I}_{\text{R}_\text{L}}=\frac{1101}{24220}\approx45.4583\space\text{mA}\tag7$$
2. \$\text{R}_\text{L}=\frac{1}{10}\$:
   $$\text{I}_{\text{R}_\text{L}}=\frac{110001}{2202220}\approx49.9501\space\text{mA}\tag7$$
3. \$\text{V}_\text{op}\$ when \$\text{R}_\text{L}=10\$:
   $$\text{V}_\text{op}=\frac{5500}{1211}\approx4.5417\space\text{V}\tag8$$
4. \$\text{V}_\text{op}\$ when \$\text{R}_\text{L}=\frac{1}{10}\$:
   $$\text{V}_\text{op}=\frac{5500}{110111}\approx49.9496\space\text{mV}\tag9$$